# "Lucha" vs "Pelea": what's the difference?

Tags: vocabulario, sinónimos

The dictionary translates both as fight or struggle. Is there any subtle difference in usage or context, or is it just a matter of personal choice? Which of the two is preferred in Latin America (Mexico in particular), in case they have no lexical difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that `Lucha` has a broader meaning, while `Pelea` is a physical fight, a quarrel or discussion. For example you could use `Lucha` like

> Lucha contra el cáncer
>
> Lucha contra los elementos, nieve, lluvia, etc
>
> Lucha consigo mismo, para superar sus tentaciones.

`Lucha` can imply a physical fight, but with a boarder sense or menaing:

> Los aliados **lucharon** contra los nazis en la segunda guerra mundial

You could not substitute `lucha` with `pelea` there, because is not a physical fight or a quarrel.

> Los dos hombres se pelearon a puñetazos.
>
> Se peleó con su jefe por el pago de las horas extras

(this means not physically, but verbally).

You can also say

> Los dos hermanos están **peleados** y no se hablan. Se **pelearon** hace mucho tiempo y todavía no han hecho las paces.

Comment: As the examples show, "lucha" can also mean "effort", "struggle".

Answer (score 7):

`Lucha` refers to a **struggle** while `Pelea` refers to literal fighting.

And even though `lucha` also refers the acting of wrestling, wrestling itself is a struggle in itself.

Answer (score 4):

Colombia: Lucha is referred as **struggle** and *Pelea* as engaging in a fight that should not only be physical but also legal, verbal.